# select All checkbox in JSF without using Javascript

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to select/unselect all checkboxes in the datatable using a single checkbox. As I am trying to set it on the server, I am unable to do so. I have looked around for solutions but could not get how to accomplish on the server side.

Here is the code.

xhtml file###

```
<rich:column styleClass="center-aligned-text">
         <f:facet name="header">
          <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAll" title="selectAll" valueChangeListener="#{workspace.selectAllComponents}">
           <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="listcomponents"/>
          </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
         </f:facet>

         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectComponent" 
          value="#{workspace.selectedComponentIds[componentInfo.id]}">
         </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </rich:column>
```

Java File

```
// Select All and delete
 public void selectAllComponents(ValueChangeEvent event){

  // If the check all button is checked, set all the checkboxes as selected 
  if(!selectAll)
  {
   changeMap(selectedComponentIds,true);
   setSelectAll(true);
  }
  else // If the button is unchecked, unselect all the checkboxes
  { 
   changeMap(selectedComponentIds,false);
   setSelectAll(false);
  }
 }

 public void changeMap(Map<Long,Boolean> selectedComponentMap, Boolean blnValue){
  if(selectedComponentMap != null){
   Iterator<Long> itr = selectedComponentMap.keySet().iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()){
    selectedComponentMap.put(itr.next(), blnValue);
   }
   setSelectedComponentIds(selectedComponentMap);
  }
 }
```

I am marking all the values in the list as `true` when the checkbox is checked and `false` when unchecked.

But the page doesn't reload the data properly.

Is my method to approach to the problem correct? Or is there a efficient alternative?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929037/select-and-unselect-list-of-checkboxes-with-single-checkbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the `ValueChangeEvent` occurs before the update model phase, so the value you change gets overwritten.
Do this in the `public void selectAllComponents(ValueChangeEvent event)`

```
if (event.getPhase() != PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
    event.setPhase(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATON);
    event.queue();
 } else {
    //do your stuff here
 }
```

Comment: correct method names are getPhaseId() and setPhaseId() as described in spec http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/event/FacesEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

Or just before your code add next line code in your original method

selectAll = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();

Comment: It didn't work for me without including the code given in the Adam's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942060/select-all-checkbox-in-jsf-without-using-javascript?rq=1