# Selectall checkbox in jsf

Tags: jsf

I need to implement a select-all check box in jsf. here is the jsf code for check boxes. Since I'm new to JSF, can u please help me..

```
<rich:column id="selectCheckbox" label="#{msg.wkfSelection}" rendered="#{(circuitWorkflowDataModel.workflowStateSelected eq circuitWorkflowDataModel.initialState) or (circuitWorkflowDataModel.uncorelated)}">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{msg.wkfSelection}" />
</f:facet>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="gridChkBox"
value="#{gridRow.rowSelected}" valueChangeListener="#{circuitWorkflowDataModel.isBtnDisabled}" immediate="true">
<a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="updatepopup"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>        
</rich:column>
```

and here is the managed bean. Due to some reasons i cant use javascript or jQuery.
Thanks in advance

```
public void isBtnDisabled(ValueChangeEvent vce) throws Exception {
        if(Boolean.valueOf(vce.getNewValue().toString())){
            dataRowCount++;
        }else{dataRowCount--;}

        if(dataRowCount > 0)
            this.setUpdateButtonActive(true);
        else
            this.setUpdateButtonActive(false);
    }
public boolean isUpdateButtonActive() {
        return !updateButtonActive;
    }

    public void setUpdateButtonActive(boolean updateButtonActive) {
        this.updateButtonActive = updateButtonActive;
    }
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem.. did you try anything..

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942060/select-all-checkbox-in-jsf-without-using-javascript

Comment: i need add a selectAll check box inside the <h:facet>header</h:facet> and since i'm new to JSF i'm having troubles doing so. Can u please help me.. Thanks