# JSF2 h:SelectBooleanCheckbox select all with one

Tags: select, jsf-2, checkbox, boolean, selectall

I had found a script to select all `<input type="checkbox">` with only one. Now I tried it with a `h:SelectBooleanCheckbox`. But it failed. How can I select my list (in datatable columns) of SelectBooleanCheckbox with one and maybe javascript for client side?

Comment: [Select and unselect list of checkboxes with single checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2929134/696299)

Comment: Oh, I forgot the ID from the other checkboxes, thank you. :)